# Does the NOT function in SQL only allow one possible factor?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Morning- I am having a bit of a problem today getting a NOT filter to work in SQL 2012.

I have a list of 6030 records, and am filtering by a field called mat_ref.  There are particular names that I do not want to have in the resulting dataset.  So I filtered as follows:

```
SELECT        mat_ref AS [Client Name], ccode
FROM            lntmu11.matter
WHERE        (mat_ref <> 'McAdams')
```

And this works fine.  But the moment that I add in more variables to the WHERE statement, I get no change.  The number of records does not change, despite the fact that I know this field has both a Thompson and a McAdams value.

```
SELECT        mat_ref AS [Client Name], ccode
FROM            lntmu11.matter
WHERE        (mat_ref <> 'McAdams') OR
                     (mat_ref = 'Thompson')
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you get the expected output for this query: SELECT        mat_ref AS [Client Name], ccode
FROM            lntmu11.matter
WHERE        (mat_ref = 'Thompson');

Comment: I didn't get it. What do you expect? All records that don't have neither 'McAdams' or 'Thompson'? Or don't have 'McAdams' but have 'Thompson'?

Comment: *‘…despite the fact that I know this field has both a Thompson and a McAdams value’* – a single field having two values at the same time? what exactly do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the filtering using `not in`:

```
SELECT mat_ref AS [Client Name], ccode
FROM lntmu11.matter
WHERE mat_ref NOT IN ('McAdams', 'Thompson');
```

Answer (score 5):

This is Boolean logic rather than anything else. You're searching for rows where

```
mat_ref is NOT EQUAL to McAdams
OR
mat_ref is EQUAL to Thompson
```

This will return every row as McAdams is not equal to Thompson.

I think you wanted to use AND and a not equals.

```
WHERE mat_ref <> 'McAdams'
  AND mat_ref <> 'Thompson'
```

This is equivalent to:

```
WHERE NOT ( mat_ref = 'McAdams' OR mat_ref = 'Thompson' )
```

Alternatively you could use NOT IN:

```
WHERE mat_ref NOT IN ('McAdams', 'Thompson')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `NOT IN`

```
SELECT  mat_ref AS [Client Name], ccode
FROM    lntmu11.matter
WHERE   mat_ref Not IN ('McAdams', 'Thompson')
```